# need a square sign the same size as proof's environment square

Tags: proof-package

There is a square sign in the end of proof environment. I proved something outside of proof environment. Because I had to have 'Proof of Theorem 3',
I need to put a square as the same size as proof square. this `\square` is too small. any solution?

Comment: I am guessing `\Box`. If this does not fit, give a `MWE`.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense without code others can copy and try as is

Comment: If you are using `amsthm` then `\qed` to make a box flush right, or `\qedsymbol` just to make the box on its own.

Comment: You can simply do `\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{label}]` followed by `\end{proof}` at the end. Here `label` stands for the actual label you used in the said theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `amsthm.sty` then its simple as suggested by `egreg` and the usage is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}[Proof of ...]
....
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

As you are not providing any `MWE` I assumed that you are using standard `LaTeX` class file...